# Render json and sort issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This following is my model, For easier reading, I cut some code:

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base

    def Joiners

    # Never mind , this is a complex sql, i think you do not need to read it.

    Joiners = Ploy.connection.select_all("SELECT count(users.id) as joiner FROM `ploys` INNER JOIN `participants` ON `participants`.`ploy_id` = `ploys`.`id` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `participants`.`user_id` where `participants`.`ploy_id`= #{self.id}")
    Joiners.rows[0][0]

    end

    def as_json(options={})
        super(methods: :Joiners)
    end
```

If i use

```
render json: @Meeting
```

It will render a JSON with *Joiners* attribute .

```
{
  "Meeting":{
   ...

   "Joiners":15,

   ...
  }

  "Meeting":{
   ...

   "Joiners":13,

   ...
  }

}
```

So:

> How can i sort by **Joiners** ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to order it in a query result by using SQL ORDER BY